# Instance variable as return values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following class with the following method(s):

```
class Ad
  def generate
    # Find logo
    @logo = create_logo(arg1,arg2...)
  end

  def create_logo(arg1,arg2,..)
    #Logic that sets @logo
    return @logo
  end
end
```

So, as you can see I am using an @instance_variable as return values and receiving values of methods. I believe that by doing so, methods are more testable and somehow it makes the code clear, but do you think this is correct in Ruby?

Or this would be more correct:

```
class Ad
  def generate
    # Find logo
    create_logo(arg1,arg2...)
  end

  def create_logo(arg1,arg2,..)
    #Logic that sets @logo
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you using instance variables as arguments?

Comment: Ok. My question would be more something like... Is it normal for a method to return an instance variable? Or should just be modified inside the method?

Comment: @Linuxios adapted the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code review

Comment: Rune FS - This is not a code review. I am trying to find out if this is a correct approach in Ruby programming.

Comment: BTW, your title seems a bit misleading, as nowhere have you used the instance variable as a method argument.

Comment: Neither is "more correct".  Don't create an instance variable where one is not needed and, by convention, don't prepend "return" to the last statement executed.  Hence, your second form is what would normally be seen.  btw, it was you who "adapted the question", not @Linuxios. Language is important! :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I think he meant `@Linuxios: adapted the question`.

Comment: @Linuxiou: or, "I adapted the question".  That was my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is much more similar to a functional programming approach, except I'd guess that it will have none of the benefits of function programming because it is doing file IO, side effects, etc.

Ask yourself this:

**Is the return value of this method *solely* the result of its arguments, and it has no side effects? (setting instance vars, file IO, database, etc.)**

If the answer is yes, than create_logo should be implemented like this:

```
def create_logo(arg1,arg2,..)
  logo = some_logic()
end
```

And called with a set to `@logo`. If not, this whole pretend almost function programming thing is useless.

The benefit of this type of implementation is that you can unit test it, it is a limited, small **self contained** part of your program, and it is simple. If the above question's answer is a no, it will do nothing for you.

Comment: Sometimes I have problem explaining myself. I am so sorry. My question was more related as...Should the instance variables be set in the methods, or they should be set as returning values of the methods like ``@logo = create_logo`` - instead of create_logo setting ``@logo``

Comment: So, if the instance variable is not returned but just set in the method, I guess is difficult to test what this method does to it, right?

Comment: @HommerSmith: Again, it depends on the work create_logo has to do to create the logo. If it is a method that relies completely on it's arguments, use the first. If it is more of an internal utility method for your class that has side effects, set it inside create_logo. Don't worry, I'm not being very clear today either.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Not really, because you can always run the method and just read the value of the instance variable afterwords.

Comment: But don't do both, which boils down to a redundant `@logo = @logo` right? I thought that was the original question.

Comment: @Kal: Obviously, never do both. (That was the original question, but there was an edit).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're essentially saying `@logo = @logo`, which seems like a strange thing to do. I'd be assigning a value to `@logo`in just one place, either in the `generate` method (and just use a local variable in `create_logo` if you need to, or set `@logo` in `create_logo` as per your second example.